# Will ARCORE work on Huawei Mate 10? it is working on p20 line and they have the exact same hardware except one less camera lens

Tags: arcore

It is weird for me to come here and see that P2 line is ARCore capable but mate 10 line is not, and I would like to know why if the hardware in P20 Pro is almost the same except for the RAM and one more lens, it just doesn't make any sense for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it has something about calibrating each phone based on the camera and motion sensors, and their locations on the phone. So even though their specifications might seem similiar there still are differences on location of the sensors and the cameras.
They might add support in the future.

Keep checking [this](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) page for supported devices, as I remember when it first became available it was not supported on devices like Galaxy S8 and S8+ and later support was added so keep an eye out for it.

Comment: thanks bud, i understand that part of calibrating every phone, just seems weird to me the construction and component distribution is almost identical, i was thinking it was due to Mali GPU, but samsung is also using mali on galaxy line so it will not be an impediment.